# http post request in reactjs not working

Tags: reactjs, http, express, post, fetch-api

I am trying to make a http post request from my reactjs application to express that locally hosted as well. I dont need to pass anything from this post request (no params needed), i just want the request to go through. All params have been specified in my express code. I am running my reactjs application locally in a different port. Here is how i am doing it.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/send', { 'mode': 'no-cors' }, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: {
            }
        });
```

This link works on the postman, just this http post method isn't working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: No error is generated. Nothing happens

Comment: In my express code i am trying to trigger sendgrid - i am following this post as ref (https://medium.com/@Keithweaver_/sending-emails-using-sendgrid-with-node-js-1ed879a94f7b)

Comment: What does the Network tab in your dev tools say? Are you getting any status codes? Is there an OPTIONS request firing off first?

Comment: What port is your client server running on and what port is your api server running on?

Comment: client is running on 3000 and api server is running on 8080

Comment: Could you show in what context and how are you running this function? (show the React component which is invoking this http request)

Comment: submitData(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
               
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/send', { 'mode': 'no-cors' }, {
            method: 'post',
            //headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: {
                
            }
        });

    }

Comment: Does it have anything to do with you using fetch with 3 parameters? I thought fetch has 2? `fetch(url, options)`

Comment: i tried that as well, but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, it is working when I remove ,

```
{ 'mode': 'no-cors' }
```

Also, assuming you're `body:` has content (it's empty right now so therefore wouldnt do anything on a POST request): you should add `JSON.stringify()` to the body. So:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
          //content here
        })
```

If `cors` is giving you issues, there's an easy way to fix that on the back end (specifically with rails).